# Confirm not working with rails (version 6.11)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a application with rails 6.11 ,but confirm is not working .I have tried many option ,but still it is not working.
I want to confirm before deleting a record in database.
Following are related files with code:
**showboard.html.erb**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Screen Size</th>
            <th>Viewership</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% @board2.each do |board| %>
        <tr>
        <td> <%=board.name %></td>
        <td> <%=board.company_name %></td>
        <td> <%=board.status %></td>
        <td> <%=board.price %></td>
        <td> <%=board.screen_size %></td>
        <td> <%=board.viewership_count %></td>
        <td> <%=board.tpye %></td>
        <td> <%=board.location %></td>
        <td>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_showboard_path(board.id),data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' },class: "btn btn-primary btn-user"%>
        
        <%= button_to "Delete", showboard_path(board.id) , method: :delete,form: { data: {confirm: "Are you sure?" } } , class: "btn btn-danger btn-user" %></td>
        
        </tr>
            <%end%>
    </tbody>
```

**showboard controller:**

```
class ShowboardsController < ApplicationController
    
    def showboards
        @board = Board.all
        @user = Owner.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
        @board2 = Board.where(company_name: @user.company_name)
    end
    def edit
        @board = Board.find(params[:id])
    end
    def update
        
        @board = Board.find(params[:id])
        if @board.update(board_params)
            redirect_to showboards_path
        else
            render edit    
        end    
    end
    def destroy
        @board = Board.find(params[:id])
        if @board.destroy
            flash[:notice] ="Board deleted successfully!"
            redirect_to showboards_path 
        end
    end    
    private
    
    def board_params
        params.permit(:name, :company_name, :screen_size, :location, :price, :tpye, :status, :viewership_count)
    end
    
end
```

**application.js**

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

Looking forward to see your responses.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. .I have tried many option ,but still it is not working" is useless information - it tells us nothing about what you have actually done to resolve the issue and will just elicit an eye roll from experienced developers. Instead tell us what actual steps you have tried and what you have researched. Have you done any basic debugging steps like checking the browser console and the sources tab in your browser  so that the correct JS is being delivered to the client? Have you started the webpacker dev server?

Comment: My bad , I have tried options like enclosing confirm in 'form' and using it with link_to and button_to .Also i tried with turbo keyword as well. Like   data: { turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' } . Also i am not master of Rails,but i have checked it in browser,but i have no idea about web packer.Can you guide me further for debugging.Thanks

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: <%= link_to "Dangerous zone", dangerous_zone_path,data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
above is what i got there and i have used same ..